# Create a button program programmatically in a seperate class

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am developing a snake game and for that I created 3 classes: Player, Control, and Grid. For my question, I would like to create the play button programmatically in which the function of creating a button is in the Control class and this function is called in the ViewController.m

In ViewController.h, I defined

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) Control *control; //object of Control class
@property (weak) IBOutlet UIButton *button;
```

In ViewController.m:

```
self.control = [[Control alloc] init];
[control createButton:_viewC Button:_button]; //_viewC is the view where the button will be shown
[_button addTarget:self action:@selector(play) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside]; //since play method in ViewController.m
```

In Control class:

```
-(void)createButton:(UIView*)view Button:(UIButton*)button
{
    button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [button setTitle:@"Play" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button setTitleColor:[UIColor blueColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal ];
    button.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    button.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:10];
    button.layer.cornerRadius = 10;
    button.frame = CGRectMake(35, 30, 70, 40);
    [view addSubview:button];
}
```

The problem is when I run the game and press the button, no action happens! can someone help me with this. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the code in the 'play' method is correct you can try setting the target in the Control class by changing the declaration to:

```
-(void)createButton:(UIView*)view Button:(UIButton*)button Selector:(SEL)selector
```

Then add this within that method:

```
[button addTarget:self.superview action:selector forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Finally in ViewController.m change the line to this:

```
[control createButton:_viewC Button:_button selector:@selector(play)];
```

and remove the line underneath.

Comment: I got an error "UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));"

Comment: Have you added -(void)createButton:(UIView*)view Button:(UIButton*)button Selector:(SEL)selector; in the .h (header file)?